# Need help wit heartrate calculation for watch

Tags: math, wear-os, pseudocode

So I'm trying to animate a fake heartbeat for my Android wear watchface. I have an API that grabs the heartrate in BPM and the current millisecond now I'm trying to use an equation to make an image "beat" to the BPM. Here's the psuedocode:

```
IF (Millis / HeartRate) % (1000 / HeartRate) <= 1)
    Opacity = 100;
ELSE
    Opacity = 75;
ENDIF
```

I'm really not sure if I calculated it properly. I don't think the image is properly flashing at the correct rate. Any help with the math would be appreciatred!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value in BPM is a frequency, rather than a period of time:

```
b BPM = b / 60s = b/60 * s^-1
```

The period of the oscillation is

```
T = 1/f = 60s / b = 60/b s
```

If we have a time in milliseconds, then we can work out the modulo vs the period:

```
remainderInSeconds = CurrentTimeInSeconds % T
         = (CurrentTimeInMilliseconds * 1e-3) % T
         = (CurrentTimeInMilliseconds * 1e-3) % (60/BeatsPerMinute)

fraction = remainderInSeconds / Period
         = [(CurrentTimeInMilliseconds * 1e-3) % T] / T
         = (CurrentTimeInMilliseconds * 1e-3 / T) % 1
         = (CurrentTimeInMilliseconds * 1e-3 / (60/BeatsPerMinute)) % 1
         = (CurrentTimeInMilliseconds * 1e-3 * BeatsPerMinute / 60)) % 1
         = (CurrentTimeInMilliseconds * BeatsPerMinute / 60e3)) % 1
```

Then you can check whether the fraction is below your threshold; if you want the pulse to last a 20th of the period, then check if fraction < 1/20.

Alternatively just calculate the remainder in seconds, if you want the pulse to last a specific amount of time rather than a portion of the period.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile a new code using a different variable from the watch API. This other variable is essentially a number between 0 and 359 which steps up at mere decimals per frame. (The variable is normally used for a smooth motion second hand).

I also decided to use a sine wave and RGB shaders instead of opacity. Here is the new code

```
Green = 0
Blue = 0
Red = 100 * math.sin(HeartRate * SecondsRotationSmooth / 60)
```

Using this particular variable isn't ideal, but it at least gives me a better looking code. If anyone wants to give a better answer please do!